# Specify optional keyword argument in constructor flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
  final Widget child;
  final Colors color;

  const FlexibleContainer({required this.child, Colors? this.color, Key? key}) : super(key: key);
```

I get error in this.color  - `parameter type Colors is incompatible with field type Colors`

Comment: change ``final Colors color;`` to ``final Colors? color;`` and ``Colors? this.color`` to only ``this.color``;

Answer (score -1):

```
  final Widget child;
  final Color? color;

  const NotificationHandler({required this.child, this.color, Key? key});
```